# Inner shadow effect in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, shadow

According to the [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18636) there is no inset attribute in ShadowBox yet. Is there any workaround how to emulate inner shadow right now in flutter.

I like to achieve inner shadow effects like you can see on the following images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well there is always a simpler way to do it. Using **packages**: Here is a good package if you gotta make a neumorphic design --> [flutter_neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k8o4.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k8o4.gif) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzzV8.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzzV8.gif) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dSc8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dSc8.png)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          const BoxShadow(
            color: your_shadow_color,
          ),
          const BoxShadow(
            color: your_bg_color,
            spreadRadius: -12.0,
            blurRadius: 12.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Good answer. Although `Colors.transparent` and `Offset(0, 0)` are default values, so those 3 lines can be deleted.

Comment: I don't understand that how it brings the desired inner shadow. I add shadows inside decoration but cannot see any inner shadow effect.

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş the container has to be empty and can't have `color` set.

Comment: Nice, but I was looking for card style like CRED application. -Offset(value,value) worked for me.

Comment: In flutter version 2.10, negative values of blurRadius, throws an error.

Comment: Nice and simple. +1

Comment: Outdated answer. spreadRadius can't be negative

Comment: Tried and worked in 2024!

Answer (score 28):

Here is what I do:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class InnerShadow extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const InnerShadow({
    Key key,
    this.blur = 10,
    this.color = Colors.black38,
    this.offset = const Offset(10, 10),
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final double blur;
  final Color color;
  final Offset offset;

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    final _RenderInnerShadow renderObject = _RenderInnerShadow();
    updateRenderObject(context, renderObject);
    return renderObject;
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _RenderInnerShadow renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..color = color
      ..blur = blur
      ..dx = offset.dx
      ..dy = offset.dy;
  }
}

class _RenderInnerShadow extends RenderProxyBox {
  double blur;
  Color color;
  double dx;
  double dy;

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child == null) return;

    final Rect rectOuter = offset & size;
    final Rect rectInner = Rect.fromLTWH(
      offset.dx,
      offset.dy,
      size.width - dx,
      size.height - dy,
    );
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas..saveLayer(rectOuter, Paint());
    context.paintChild(child, offset);
    final Paint shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcATop
      ..imageFilter = ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blur, sigmaY: blur)
      ..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcOut);

    canvas
      ..saveLayer(rectOuter, shadowPaint)
      ..saveLayer(rectInner, Paint())
      ..translate(dx, dy);
    context.paintChild(child, offset);
    context.canvas..restore()..restore()..restore();
  }
}
```

then just use it somewhere:

```dart
InnerShadow(
  blur: 5,
  color: const Color(0xFF477C70),
  offset: const Offset(5, 5),
  child: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      color: Color(0xFFE9EFEC),
    ),
    height: 100,
  ),
)
```

The result:
[image: result]

Comment: This code was released as [sums_inner](https://pub.dev/packages/sums_inner) on Pub, btw. The code in the GitHub repository looked surprisingly familiar!

Comment: I don't unfortunately; first thing I would give a shot is writing to SO because it's a license violation of the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) from what I understand (because no attribution). Maybe they can give you more information then. As a sidenote: Not sure if calling other people "Scum" is accepted here (regardless of what they have done) :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. You are right re the used term, my bad. I was not able to edit my comment, so just copying it here: 

Yeah, he did not even bother to change a single line and put his own copyright. Do you have any idea where to write a claim to?

Comment: @AlexandrPriezzhev I really like the answer provided above. Can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514745/how-to-create-an-inner-shadow-for-custom-shape-in-flutter. It's of similar type

Comment: @SarveshDalvi, you can use my answer given here. It works well for any custom shape.

Comment: @AlexandrPriezzhev thanks for this, but can you give a hint on how to optimize the performance? I am using 35 widgets wrapped with this inner shadow and I am getting pretty bad fps.

Comment: @AlexandrPriezzhev could you please explain how exactly does the paint method work? I'm stuck trying to decipher the saveLayer methods and the order in which they are called together with the draw methods.

Comment: @AlexandrPriezzhev. Inner shadow is not working if it contains a child like ElevatedButton or ListView.

Comment: Can I use a transparent container? Here the widget disapear when not define a opaque color

Comment: doesn't work in 3.16, need some updates especially the `context.paintChild` method

Answer (score 15):

I've taken the answer by @AlexandrPriezzhev and improved it to use the standard `Shadow` class (including the semantics of its `offset` field), added support for multiple shadows, and shaved off a `saveLayer()` call which should make it a bit more efficient:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class InnerShadow extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const InnerShadow({
    Key? key,
    this.shadows = const <Shadow>[],
    Widget? child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final List<Shadow> shadows;

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    final renderObject = _RenderInnerShadow();
    updateRenderObject(context, renderObject);
    return renderObject;
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _RenderInnerShadow renderObject) {
    renderObject.shadows = shadows;
  }
}

class _RenderInnerShadow extends RenderProxyBox {
  late List<Shadow> shadows;

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child == null) return;
    final bounds = offset & size;

    context.canvas.saveLayer(bounds, Paint());
    context.paintChild(child!, offset);

    for (final shadow in shadows) {
      final shadowRect = bounds.inflate(shadow.blurSigma);
      final shadowPaint = Paint()
        ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcATop
        ..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(shadow.color, BlendMode.srcOut)
        ..imageFilter = ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: shadow.blurSigma, sigmaY: shadow.blurSigma);
      context.canvas
        ..saveLayer(shadowRect, shadowPaint)
        ..translate(shadow.offset.dx, shadow.offset.dy);
      context.paintChild(child!, offset);
      context.canvas.restore();
    }

    context.canvas.restore();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas! Thanks for your version. Works pretty well. 
I get a bug though (also in Alexanders version)

```

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Object has been disposed.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    InnerShadow 
```

This is probably caused by `saveLayer` in conjunction with `paintChild`. I could not find a fix yet.
See also https://github.com/luigi-rosso/flutter-inner-shadow/issues/1
Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Is solved, see https://github.com/luigi-rosso/flutter-inner-shadow/commit/e05b7c512a0deafe53a9c3893b4f116969015f59

Comment: @Richard Thanks for noting that! An edit was proposed some days ago that made a change like that to this post, but without stating the reason, so it got rejected. I've made the same changes here now.

Comment: I am getting The method 'paintChild' isn't defined for the type 'Canvas'.

Comment: @user3808307 Edited; it's a method on the context not the canvas.

Comment: I used this also somewhat succesful but sometiimes smaller children mess with the shadows. Like a TextField child. I don't know why

Answer (score 6):

James's answer creates a shadow outside which warps the shape. Mohammed's answer is a gradient and not proper shadow but Alexandr's solution works perfectly for me with a small fix! rectInner has to be updated.

```
final Rect rectInner = Rect.fromLTWH(
    offset.dx,
    offset.dy,
    size.width,
    size.height,
);
```

Comment: Changing `rectInner` like this removed the shadow from the bottom and right side. [Alexandr's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60530625/3291390) worked great for me as is.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can solve this problem by using normal box shadow and two containers - the outer one acting as a background and inner one providing the shadow.

Code:

```
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              blurRadius: 10,
                              spreadRadius: 10)
                        ]),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 272,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Content goes here"),
                    ),
                  )))),
```

Produces:
[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 4):

You can use do it using multiple BoxShadow, where the first one (below) is darker, and a lighter one on top, and top it off with the a border with greyish color to make the container pops.

Code:

```
Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                              BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
                            ),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 1, spreadRadius: 0),
                              BoxShadow(color: Colors.white, blurRadius: 10, spreadRadius: 5),
                            ]),
                        child: Icon(Icons.pause, size: 70, color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

james's answer did not do the trick for me.

So I simply made it out by placing an inner **Gradient** layer above my container/image, thus, I had the kind of inner shadow I wanted (only from the bottom in my case).

```dart
Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: AssetImage('images/bg.jpg') /*NetworkImage(imageUrl)*/,
          ),
        ),
        height: 350.0,
      ),
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
            end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
              Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.0),
              Colors.black54,
            ],
            stops: [0.95, 1.0],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with just using a package I found this one works quite well.

https://pub.dev/packages/sums_inner

Answer (score 0):

Found this package: https://pub.dev/packages/inner_shadow_widget

Works perfect for me:

```
InnerShadow(
 blur: 3,
 offset: const Offset(2, 2),
 child: Image.asset('path'),
),
```

without inner shadow

[image]

with inner shadow

[image]