# How to create an inner shadow for custom shape in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas

Below is the custom shape I've want to give an inner shadow to :

[image]

Below is the code I've used to create this shape : (The text part is not included in the code)

```
class TitleContainerPaint extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: implement paint

    Paint x = Paint()..color = Colors.grey ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    Path a = Path();

    a.moveTo(size.height * 0.5, 0);
    a.lineTo(size.width * 0.3, 0);
    a.cubicTo(size.width * 0.325, 0, size.width * 0.325, size.height * 0.5 - 10, size.width * 0.35, size.height * 0.5 - 10);
    a.lineTo(size.width * 0.825, size.height * 0.35);
    a.cubicTo(size.width * 0.85, size.height * 0.5 - 10, size.width * 0.85, size.height * 0.15, size.width * 0.875, size.height * 0.15);
    a.lineTo(size.width - size.height * 0.25, size.height * 0.15);
    a.arcTo(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width - size.height * 0.35,size.height * 0.5), radius: size.height * 0.35), -pi/2, pi, false);
    a.lineTo(size.width * 0.875, size.height * 0.85);
    a.cubicTo(size.width * 0.85, size.height * 0.85, size.width * 0.85, size.height * 0.5 + 10, size.width * 0.825, size.height * 0.5 + 10);
    a.lineTo(size.width * 0.35, size.height * 0.65);
    a.cubicTo(size.width * 0.325, size.height * 0.5 + 10, size.width * 0.325, size.height, size.width * 0.3, size.height);
    a.lineTo(size.height * 0.5, size.height);
    a.arcTo(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.height * 0.5,size.height * 0.5), radius: size.height * 0.5), pi/2, pi, false);

    canvas.drawPath(a, x);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }


}
```

As mentioned in the question, my goal is to add an inner shadow to this shape like the image below :

[image]

Can someone please help me achieve this?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: check `MaskFilter.blur` constructor

Comment: @pskink Could you please provide a code showing how to do it properly. I tried mask filer.blur before, BlurStyle.normal  provided the shadow I wanted but it was both outer and inner, I can overlap it with a clip path to hide the outer shadow but I don't think its a good option, I also tried inner and outer BlurStyle but its provided some wierd results.

Comment: what is the height and width of your paint?

Comment: @TipuSultan Height is 60 (constant value) and width is 70% of screen width (scaled using MediaQuery)

Comment: `var r = (Offset.zero & size);
canvas.clipRect(r);
var r1 = r.deflate(32);
var p = Path()
..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
..addRect(r)
..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(r1, Radius.circular(64)));
canvas.drawPath(p, Paint()..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, 8)`

Comment: @pskink I'll try this out tonight any will notify you.

Answer (score 2):

Use your paint like this:

```
Paint x = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.inner, 5)
      ..color = Colors.grey;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose the same approach as given in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60530625/3445280). In your case you just use the `CustomPaint` widget as the child for the inner shadow widget:

```
InnerShadow(
  shadow: const BoxShadow(
    blurRadius: 20,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  child: CustomPaint(painter: TitleContainerPaint()),
)
```

The complete code could be found here https://codepen.io/priezz/pen/abBRmrb

P.S. Your `TitleContainerPaint` gives slightly different shape than given in your example image, you'll probably need to tweak it. Maybe it's just the issue with Flutter for Web.

Comment: it doesnt work well with  circle container (BoxShape.circle)

Answer (score 0):

//change the alpha color of your grey color like this

```
canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.grey.withAlpha(50), -4.0, false);
```

Here the shadow will be inner.