Add inner shadow with CustomPaint in Flutter
I have a fill path that creates a simple triangle: M49.5 0L92.3683 94.5L6.63174 94.5L49.5 0Z.
The triangle is being drawn correctly by using CustomPainter and canvas.drawPath().
Now I need to add an inner shadow like in the image:

I've tried adding a maskFilter:
canvas.drawPath(
          path.shift(Offset(0, 4)),
          Paint()
            ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
            ..color = Colors.black
            ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(
                BlurStyle.inner, Shadow.convertRadiusToSigma(4)));

but it is covering the whole triangle:

How can I add the inner shadow like in the first image?

Refer this

Use the stack widget for the inner shadow of the triangle, resizing the other custompaints slightly smaller than the main custompaint.

Also refer Inner shadow effect in Flutter.

try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514745/how-to-create-an-inner-shadow-for-custom-shape-in-flutter#comment117586673_66514745

class InnerShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Path path = Path()..moveTo(100, 50)..lineTo(0, 200)..lineTo(200, 200)..close();
    final Paint paint = Paint()..color = Color(0xFF74B5EAFF);

    // 绘制矩形
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    // 绘制内部阴影
    final Path innerPath = Path()
      ..addPath(path, Offset.zero)
      ..addPath(path.shift(Offset(0, 5)), Offset.zero)
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
    canvas.save();
    final Paint shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 5)
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOut;
    canvas.clipPath(path);

    canvas.drawPath(innerPath, shadowPaint);

    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}


it did not work
