# How to draw inner shadow possibly with drawShadow

Tags: flutter-layout

I need to draw an inner shadow only in the top of a container

Currently I am using `foregroundDecoration` with a liner gradient. I doesn't look very well, I don't like the finishing look.

I see there is this method [drawShadow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawShadow.html), I don't know how to use it nor if it is appropriate for inner shadows

Paint maybe would work too

I would like to use `paint` or `drawShadow`, not `BoxShadow` as it is not working for me

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inner shadow effect in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061964/inner-shadow-effect-in-flutter)

Comment: I don't see any shadow when I use this, IDK