# Depressed/pressed button design - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, button

I'm relatively new to flutter. As I was looking for UI, to replicate for practise, I came across one with a beautiful button. Below is the picture of the design for reference.
[image]

My aim is to let the user tap the button and it should change the button's design/state from lifted to depressed i.e. the shadows should change from falling around the button to falling inside the button.

I managed to replicate the square button at the bottom, but I could not replicate the one on the top. 
Below is the code of the bottom square button from the picture:

```
Center(
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      height: 300.0,
      width: 300.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.shade100,
            offset: Offset(_offset * -1, _offset * -1),
            blurRadius: 8.0,
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.shade500,
            offset: Offset(_offset, _offset),
            blurRadius: 8.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

For further reference, i'm attaching a similar design, but instead of a button, it's a search bar.[image]

How can I achieve this design and the feature of changing button design on tap?

Edit: My main concern is that i'm unable to replicate the "pressed" design of the button

Answer (score 1):

You can use GestureDetector for it:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: () {
        pressing = true;
    },
    onTapUp: () {
        pressing = false;
    }
```

)

Comment: The problem is that i'm not able to replicate the pressed design, i.e. the button should have shadows inside it, instead of surrounding it.

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061964/inner-shadow-effect-in-flutter