# How to create shadows like the one in the figure in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

Can anyone tell me how we can create inner shadows like this in flutter please.
[image]

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061964/inner-shadow-effect-in-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concept is knowns as Neomorphism. And you can use some package to implement it.

Below are some:

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic
- https://pub.dev/packages/neumorphic

Cheers!

Comment: This helped, thank you, but I would also like know how to do this in code, without using a package.