# Create button inner shadow flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, shadow

[image]

I have a design task. I want to create a button same as this image.

```
 GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("123");
            },
            child: Container(
              width: Get.width,
              height: 80.sp,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0.sp),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: AppColor.weightBMIGradient,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0.sp)),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

This is my code but my answer not have inner shadow. Please help me!
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55096682/15052881

Comment: I try but i not work